# Referencing an XML attribute from another xml element

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying out new things (well, im also new to xml and android). This thing came up to my mind during my brain storming. Is it possible to reference an XML element attribute for a value of an element?
(sorry the english isn't quite well)

idea :

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
    android:max="9"
    android:progress="0" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seekBar1"
    **android:text="@id/seekBar1/progress"**
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

the highlighted part. Thanks for reading and for possible answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: **No**, unfortunately it's not.

And even if it worked, there were two additional issues:

- It seems you would expect the `TextView` to be updated when the `SeekBar` progresses, which would not work even if the reference would work.
- The system had to automatically convert the progress (a float) to a String.

Comment: that pretty much answered my query, I'd like to vote up your answer but my current rep point is <15. Thanks dude.